# How to determine the optimal number of clusters and iterations on Kohonen Self-Organizing Map?

Tags: iteration, cluster-analysis, self-organizing-maps

Please help me to complete my final assignment.
There are some questions of the lecturer

- How do I determine the number of clusters on Self-Organizing Map?
- How do I determine the optimal number of iterations in the
  Self-Organizing Map?

Answer (score 3):

I won't do your assignment, but i give you some hints and hope that it gets you started:

**number of clusters algos**

- DS2L-SOM (Cabanes, Bennani, Fresnau)
- S2L-SOM
- SKM
- [PDF1](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/axis/modulad///sda11/HCSDA11-Cabanes.pdf)
- [PDF2 (Mining RFID Behavior Data using Unsupervised Learning)](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220363021_Mining_RFID_Behavior_Data_using_Unsupervised_Learning/file/9fcfd50c1b9f53d2a1.pdf)

**optimal number of iterations**

- [Growing SOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growing_self-organizing_map)
- http://www.cis.hut.fi/somtoolbox/documentation/somalg.shtml
- [Growing Neural Gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_gas) (Martinetz/Schulten)
- DemoGNG (Loos/Fritzke)

  - Java Applet for LBG, LBG-U, Neural Gas, Competitive Hebbian Learning, Growing Neural Gas, Self-organizing Map, Growing Grid, Growing Ring by
  - http://www.demogng.de/
  - https://www.youtube.com/user/demogng
  - https://github.com/rhaschke/demogng (formerly https://github.com/gittar/demogng)